# How to downgrade react Js version globally from 17 to 15.02

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Hello there how can I downgrade react version from 17.0.2 to 15.02 as I need to work on a project that is currently running on react version 15.02 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you concerned about a mismatch between your local installation of React and the one used in the project you're working on? React is a project dependency and you have the version specified for your project installed into your local `node_modules` folder inside your project. Hence, if you check out your repository and run `npm install` or `yarn`, respectively, you will have the correct version for your project (based on your package.json and package.lock) installed.

Comment: The final conclusion is not clear. Is it required to downgrade the React version from my machine? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: With a correct project set up (i.e., React dependency specified in your `package.json`) you do not need to manually tamper with the dependency versions. Should you have React installed as global dependency, you might face some issues, however, I don't see why you would do that. If that doesn't help you, you need to be more specific about the problem you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to your `package.json` file, you can change the version.

Replace `"react": "^17.0.2"` with the version you want and re-start the server.